# Infinite sequence of real numbers converging to x and y

Tags: convergence-divergence

So the question is:

Suppose $x_i$ and $y_i$ are infinite sequences of real numbers converging to x and y. Show that $(x_i + y_i)$ converges to $x+y$. Show that $x_iy_i$ converges to $xy$.

 Here's what I tried for $x_iy_i$:

$|x_i - x| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n$ $\epsilon$ $N$ such that $n \le N$. and 
$|y_i - y| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n$ $\epsilon$ $N$ such that $n \le N$. 
$(x_iy_i) \to |x_i-x||y_i-y| < \epsilon$

$|x_iy_i - xy_i - x_iy + xy| < \epsilon$
but I can't seem to figure out how to make it so that
$|x_iy_i - xy| < \epsilon$

Any hints or suggestions on what I should do to make it work? Thanks!

Comment: *Hint:* Write $|x_iy_i - xy| = | x_i(y_i - y) + y(x_i - x)| \leq | x_i(y_i - y)| + |y(x_i - x)|$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $|x_i+y_i-x-y|\le |x_i-x|+|y_i-y|$.

Another hint: $|x_i y_i-x y|\le |x_i y_i-x_i y+x_i y-x y| \le |x_i| |y_i- y|+|y||x_i  -x  |$.

Comment: Another hint: Use that a convergent series is bounded.

Comment: @Marc of course. But a sequence, not a series.

Comment: @Marc I thought I did use the definition of convergence in my proof or was I wrong? $|x_i - x| < \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$ there is an $n$ $\epsilon$ $N$ such that $n \le N$.& thanks TZakrevskiy that's really helpful